# Calendar give wrong timestamp on adding one day

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I am trying to add one day to calendar date but i am getting wrong output.
Below code i am using.

```
var cal2= Calendar.getInstance()
cal2!!.timeInMillis=cal.timeInMillis
Log.e("Time1",""+cal.timeInMillis);
cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
Log.e("Time2",""+cal2.timeInMillis);
```

> Time1: 1526478465( Wednesday, 16 May 2018 19:17:45)
>
> Time1: 1612878465(Tuesday, 9 February 2021 19:17:45 )

Comment: What is the value of cal.timeInMillis ?

Comment: The `Calendar` class is long outdated and poorly designed. For stuff like adding one day to a date-time I recommend [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It’s so much nicer to work with. For example the `ZonedDateTime` class from this API.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `cal.timeInMillis` has proper value (say today's date), your code works fine:

```
var cal = Calendar.getInstance() <-- Assumption
var cal2 = Calendar.getInstance()
cal2!!.timeInMillis=cal.timeInMillis
println("Time1: "+cal.timeInMillis);
cal2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
println("Time2: "+cal2.timeInMillis);
```

Running above code gives following output:

```
Time1: 1527159971747 (Thursday, May 24, 2018 11:06:11.747 AM)
Time2: 1527246371747 (Friday, May 25, 2018 11:06:11.747 AM)
```

Comment: try setting cal time to 1526478465 and try

Answer (score 0):

You’re somehow confusing *seconds* and *milliseconds* since the epoch. 1 526 478 465 is seconds. If you treat them as milliseconds, you get  January 18, 1970 4:01:18 PM UTC. If you add 1 day to that, you get the next value you mention (I got 1 612 878 000, it comes close). When in turn you interpret 1 612 878 465 as seconds, you get February 9, 2021 1:47:45 PM UTC. This is the same as the date-time you mention, Tuesday, 9 February 2021 19:17:45, if I assume you’re at offset +05:30 (like Asia/Kolkata or Asia/Colombo time zone).

Since there are 1000 milliseconds in a second, your confusion has caused you to add 1000 days to your date instead of 1 day.

Tip: 10 digit values are usually seoncds. 13 digit values are usually milliseconds.